# Site em 2 idioma sem mudar a URL, terei problemas com SEO?

Tags: url, seo

Estou desenvolvendo um site em 2 idiomas em PHP, na primeira vez que o usuário acessa, ele pega o idioma do navegador com `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`, caso o usuário troque de idioma, salvo essa escolha em um coockie, para seguir nesse idioma no restante da navegação ou em futuros acessos, acredito que nessa parte esteja acertando.

A minha dúvida está na URL do site, preciso mudar ela? Como site.com.br/en (caso esolha acessar em inglês)? Ou posso sempre manter a mesma URL nos 2 idiomas? Terei problemas de SEO? O Google vai indexar os 2 conteúdos?

Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar, pensando no lado do SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que a resposta oficial esta aqui:

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6144055?hl=pt

O Google-BOT não envia o `Accept-Language`, então deve-se usar urls diferentes.

Note que a Google em seus artigos recomenda usar:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="x-default">
```

Então em um artigo como `br.foo.com/1001/seo-site-com-multiplos-idiomas` no HTML apresentaria algo como

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.foo.com/1001/bar">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://de.foo.com/1001/bar">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.foo.com/1001/bar">
```

No link da google também é dito isto:

> Considere adicionar uma página substituta para idiomas não correspondentes, especialmente em seletores de idioma/país ou páginas iniciais de redirecionamento automático. Use o valor `x-default`:
>
> ```
> <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
> ```

Pessoalmente nem queria entra em "debate" sobre isto, mas ao meu ver o que parece mais fácil (ou correto) ao usuário é simplesmente apresentar os idiomas que tem e saber quais são seus publicos alvos e os idiomas, se a pessoa é de um idioma improvável talvez apontar o artigo em inglês já resolveria, mas não posso afirmar 100% (e não estou falando de SEO, estou falando da experiência do usuário real, porque esta deve ser a preocupação inicial)